# Target Self Key - how can I make it work?

Tags: rift

I recently started playing RIFT again, and this time I prefer playing a healing role. I had a question about the target self key you can set in `Settings > Interface > Combat`. I disabled Auto-Self Cast as I prefer having a modifier key held in to cast a spell on myself (Like in World of Warcraft - You hold in Alt (by default) and press the skill you need to self-cast)

In RIFT I tried to get a similar setup - In the Settings menu, described above, I set the Self Cast Key to Alt, applied my settings and returned to game. I have a healing spell on [Shift-2], which, I expect having to press [Alt-Shift-2], the spell will be cast upon myself (but it doesn't). I would like to avoid creating macros all over the place just for this function. **Are there any other additional methods I could try to get the self-cast to work?**

I unbound the 'Mark Target' Keybinds (which by default is [Alt-1] and up). Pressing [Alt-Shift-2] attempts to cast my ability which is keybinded to [2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your healing spell on `Shift-2` is a macro, you need to add `@self` before the name of the spell.

ie. `cast @self Healing Breath`

If this is not the case, it could be that you have a key combination set somewhere in your controls (you may not have been the one to set it) that by default uses `Alt-Shift` that is interfering with your ability to cast your spell.

Another thing to add to this, as far as I recall the target self binding would target you. So try pressing alt (then let go of alt) and it should target yourself, **then** press `Shift-2` and see how that works for you.

Comment: `If this is not the case, it could be that you have a key combination set somewhere in your controls (you may not have been the one to set it) that by default uses Alt-Shift that is interfering with your ability to cast your spell.` - I will test that theory . I really do not want to create macros but it's worth a shot. fortunately my level is still low and I am really doing questing content still. But some point I will start dungeons/raids/instant adventures like mad and will need to pull out all stops to heal.

Comment: Sad to say this - there is nothing I can do but make macros as you suggested